# echo php variable, in html, which is put again in a php variable

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to return html, to my ajax request.
The ajax request requests a controller method to create a view according to what is clicked.

It's a simple form. But it should have a `<select>` tag in it. 
The `<select>` tag should display different roles, with one role already selected. which can be assigned to different users.

So I tried creating an object as so:

```
 $roles = $this->database->GetAllRoles();
 $selectedRole = $this->database->GetAllRoles()->where('id', '=', $user->roles_id)->first();
 foreach($roles as $role){
    $selectObject = 
    '
    <option selected value="' . $selectedRole['id'] . '">"' . $selectedRole['name'] . '"</option>
    <option value="' . $roles->id . '">"' . $roles->name . '"</option>
    ';
 }
 $htmlFinal = 
 '
  <form>
  <!-- Form labels and inputs ... -->
  <select class="form-control" type="text">
     "' . $selectObject . '"
 ';
```

[image: It should be]

This is what it should look like, with a selected option in the form select tag, and more options when opened.

Obviously the above code doesn't work ofcourse, I tried alot of different approaches but I'm kind of stuck right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `=` on the `$selectObject` variable inside the loop, so, the variable is overriden each iteration. You could use `.=` to append the HTML in the variable. Then, you shouldn't write the selected option inside the loop, because you will add it several times. Also, you use `$roles` but in your foreach, the current element is `$role`.

```
$selectObject = '<option selected value="' . $selectedRole['id'] . '">"' . $selectedRole['name'] . '"</option>';
foreach ($roles as $role) {
    $selectObject .= '<option value="' . $role->id . '">"' . $role->name . '"</option>';
}
```

Finally, to avoid a duplicate of the selected role, you could add a `if` to add only other roles.

```
$selectObject = '<option selected value="' . $selectedRole['id'] . '">"' . $selectedRole['name'] . '"</option>';
foreach ($roles as $role) {
    if ($role->id != $selectedRole['id']) {
        $selectObject .= '<option value="' . $role->id . '">"' . $role->name . '"</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I see now how easy this was. I think I didn't see the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `foreach` loop looklike this:

```
if(array_key_exists('id',$selectedRole) &&  $selectedRole['id']==$roles->id)
     <option value="' . $roles->id . '" selected >"' . $roles->name . '"</option>
else
   <option value="' . $roles->id . '">"' . $roles->name . '"</option>
```